# Postgresql pass function parameter with casting

Tags: postgresql

I created two functions. The first function, `getProductOrder`, is getting token whose type is `character varying`. The second function is getOrderTechnicalDetails whose function parameter is `character varying`.

For example When I call getProductOrder with quotation marks that is working nothing problem the function

**Worked example**

```
select
    (select row_to_json(getOrderTechnicalDetails('991964b80d4f41a416b48ac99bdc07ad')) as techDetails),
    o.*
from 
    (select * from getProductOrder(null, '54e91016-46d0-11e7-912d-001dd8b72237', null, 9181, 1::smallint)) o
```

But I have to use dynamic parameter here problem is casting problem function can't determine casting.

When I execute this query I get syntax error. How can I solve this problem?

**Query**

```
select
    (select row_to_json(getOrderTechnicalDetails(o.token::character varying)) as techDetails),
    o.*
from 
    (select * from getProductOrder(null, '54e6341-46d0-11e7-912d-001dd8b72237', null, 9181, 1::smallint)) o
```

**Error**

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "-"
SQL state: 22P02
Context: SQL function "getordertechnicaldetails" statement 1
```

Comment: You should post code of that function causing problem: `getordertechnicaldetails`

Comment: I've bet that there is error in getProductOrder

Comment: @JustMe I bet that there isn't (or that it's not the problem here) because the error message actually says that the problem is the first statement inside function "getordertechnicaldetails".

Comment: Try to work down to a [mcve] that reproduces the error. The error message says that the problem is in "getordertechnicaldetails", so your first aim is to delete all your test code except for `Select * from getOrderTechnicalDetails('foo')`, where `'foo'` is one of the values you expect for `o.token`. You might need to first run `Select o.* From ... getProductOrder(...) as o` to find a value that causes the error. Then you can look at what the first statement inside the "getordertechnicaldetails" function is doing, and can probably take that out of the function and run it manually, simplify, etc

Comment: getordertechnicaldetails have a character varying parameter. getProductOrder return character varying but when use  quotation marks function is working. İf I use manuel value such as (select row_to_json(getOrderTechnicalDetails('FOO123)) as techDetails) it is working. But parameter must be dynamic. How can I solve?

Comment: I solved my problem. The mistake is I used wrong data type when I call  getOrderTechnicalDetails. Thanks for helping.